# I'm not understanding how an array is working

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm working on a class and was asked to code the following for loop array, but I don't understand the step by step process in how it works. Can anyone explain it to me? It's finding the square root, but I don't understand step by step how it works.

```
var oldArray = [12, 45, 6, 23, 19, 20, 20, 15, 30, 42];

// Write your code below this line
var newArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(oldArray[i] * oldArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: First thing to understand: that's not finding any square roots.

Comment: Your code does the opposite of finding square roots. It calculates squares.

Comment: using Google, [arrays in javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=arrays+in+javascript&oq=arrays+in+javascript)

Comment: Your code produces SQUARES (`oldArray[i] * oldArray[i]`, 12 * 12), not square root.

Comment: Why is this getting down voted? It's on topic and can be answered.

Comment: Mi-Creativity, that does not help at all. He probably asked the question here because he was having a hard time understanding. Sometimes websites that you find on google are not that helpful or detailed.

Comment: @ThomasJuranek Probably because it [doesn't **show** much effort](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As mentioned in other comments, there are many resources on the web (e. g. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)) that try to explain how arrays work. It is - of course - possible that there are some other obstacles the OP found and we just don't know, but in this case the StackOverflow community likes to know them.

Comment: @user289882, havethe first result of that search: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp ,  it's very detailed and simplified,  and it answers the question, and [this is from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) , in certain cases like this,  teaching him to search and read first before asking is better than giving him the answer “*You give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. You teach him to fish and you give him an occupation that will feed him for a lifetime.*”

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is finding the squares of the numbers, not the square root.  Here are some observations:

`oldArray` is just a list (array) of numbers:

```
var oldArray = [12, 45, 6, 23, 19, 20, 20, 15, 30, 42];
```

`newArray` starts out as an empty list:

```
var newArray = [];
```

The `for`-loop visits each item in `oldArray`. In every iteration, `i` is increased by one (using `i++`) as long as `i` hasn't reached the length of `oldArray`:

```
for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++)
```

`newArray.push` adds an item to the end of `newArray`. The item added is the value at the position `i` in `oldArray` (also called "the `i`-th entry of `oldArray`") multiplied with itself:

```
newArray.push(oldArray[i] * oldArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code actually gives a new array with each element being the square of the elements in the original array.

This first part initializes the array of values:

```
var oldArray = [12, 45, 6, 23, 19, 20, 20, 15, 30, 42];
```

This next part creates the new array to store the squares in.

```
var newArray = [];
```

Now for the last part. This part uses a for loop to go through each index in the original array. Each element in the array has an index, or more basically a "number" that is used to find an elements placement in the array. The index number ranges from 0 to the length of the array - 1. The -1 is since it starts at 0. Therefore this loop goes through each element in order, taking it and multiplying it by itself, and then storing it in the new array.

```
for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(oldArray[i] * oldArray[i]);
}
```

The following line is what specifically performs the "square operation". It takes the current element and then multiplies it by itself, taking in the fact that the square of n is n * n. Then it "pushes" it into the new array, or in other words adds it to the new array.

```
newArray.push(oldArray[i] * oldArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is taking each element of the oldArray and multiplying with itself and pushing it to the newArray

check this

```js
var oldArray = [12, 45, 6, 23, 19, 20, 20, 15, 30, 42];

// Write your code below this line
var newArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(oldArray[i] * oldArray[i]);
}

console.log(newArray);
```

but you need not have a for loop for this ,the same can be achieved by using map

check this snippet

```js
var oldArray = [12, 45, 6, 23, 19, 20, 20, 15, 30, 42];

// Write your code below this line
var newArray = [];

newArray = oldArray.map(function(number) {
  return number * number;
});


console.log(newArray);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Ah, too early for map() don't you think? :)

Answer (score 0):

The code as written here doesn't find the square root. It's creating a new array where each item is the square of the old array item at the same index.

```js
var oldArray = [12, 45, 6, 23, 19, 20, 20, 15, 30, 42];

// Write your code below this line
var newArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(oldArray[i] * oldArray[i]);
}

console.log(newArray)
// [144, 2025, 36, 529, 361, 400, 400, 225, 900, 1764]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the square roots:

```
var oldArray = [12, 45, 6, 23, 19, 20, 20, 15, 30, 42];

// Write your code below this line
var newArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(Math.sqrt(oldArray[i]))

  console.log(newArray);
//[3.4641016151377544, 6.708203932499369, 2.449489742783178, 4.795831523312719, 4.358898943540674, 4.47213595499958, 4.47213595499958, 3.872983346207417, 5.477225575051661, 6.48074069840786]
}
```

Okay...here's what's going on...

1. `oldArray` is basically just a set of numbers (called an array).
2. `newArray` is also a set of numbers, but starts with the set completely empty (`[]`). You're going to `push` numbers into this set/array using your `for` loop.
3. For loops basically say if this is true (or false) then do this, check again, do it again...until it's no longer true (or no longer false). In your case, you're saying that a variable called `i` = 0. Then...`i < oldArray.length;` says if `i` is less than the total number of numbers in your `oldArray` set/array, then (`i++`) add 1 to `i` (that's what `i++` means)
4. Then you're saying `push` some information into `newArray`, which is the square root (`Math.sqrt`) of `oldArray[i]`, which means the number in position `i` in your set. If `i` was 3 (remember, we're increasing `i` each time we loop), then we'd be referring to 6, which is the the third number in your array.
5. Your loop runs until `i` = 10, which is how many numbers are in your array.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Initializing the Array with the Numbers**

You can just initialize a *blank array* in JavaScript like `var Arrays=[];` Then assign some values to that array like `Arrays[0]=0; Arrays[1]=1;`So Here you are doing both works in One step,

```
var oldArray = [12, 45, 6, 23, 19, 20, 20, 15, 30, 42];
```

**2. Initializing the New Array to Store the Output**

you want a rest array to store the outputs that you want. So you are initializing this array here,

```
var newArray = [];
```

**3. Running Loop**

You are using normal `for` loop  to get every elements in the loop step by step. You can use `foreach` and some other ways to do this action also,

```
for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
  // Code inside the Loop
}
```

**4. Assign the Output to the New Array**

You are getting the output using `oldArray[i] * oldArray[i]`. Then after you are inserting that output value to the new array using `push` command. You put this line inside the loop to store every output step by step to the new array.

```
newArray.push(oldArray[i] * oldArray[i]);
```